# Are restriction enzymes active at −20 °C?

Tags: molecular-biology, restriction-enzymes

I have digested my DNA with NotI enzyme and put it in the −20 °C freezer without heat inactivating it. Can restriction enzymes work at −20 °C? Should I expect STAR activity?

Comment: I'd still recommend inactivating the enzyme or cleaning up the reaction after thawing up.

Comment: what is star activity? pls avoid acronms amap thnk y othrws t bcms unintellgbl

Comment: @AliceD *Star activity* is a pretty common term. It refers to nonspecific digestion by restriction enzymes.

Comment: @AliceD [Star activity](https://www.neb.com/tools-and-resources/usage-guidelines/star-activity) is not an acronym, it is merely restriction enzyme jargon. -edit- ninjad.

Comment: the capitals made it look like an acronym :) Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

Enzymes have temperature optima based on the organism they were isolated from. So I would predict the there is virtually no activity at −20 °C. Another consideration is that the reactions are likely to be frozen solid, so that would limit diffusion, and also slow it down. But the real question is: what are you afraid of? Just the star activity? Even if there were star activity, would that adversely affect your experiments?

Comment: I do not know, I have never had star activity before. Your answer makes sense and I think like that too but I posted the question here because there was no answer to this on the internet and I thought maybe someone here has an experience on this.

Comment: How about this paper? http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2396408/pdf/gkn182.pdf

Comment: @mdperry You should update that into your answer and perhaps include some excerpts from it, it is a great addition.

Answer (score 1):

While there is unlikely to be any activity when the enzyme is frozen, there are better methods to prevent star activity.

1: If you are running the reaction in a PCR machine, you can program the machine prior to the digest to heat up to 65 degrees for 10 minutes after the intended digestion timeframe to heat inactivate NotI. [Since NotI is a heat-labile enzyme](https://www.neb.com/products/r0189-noti), this prevents star activity by denaturing it.

2: You can use [NotI-HF](https://www.neb.com/products/r3189-noti-hf), which has been engineered by NEB to greatly reduce the amount of star activity and can therefore be left incubating at 37°C overnight.

3: You can gel purify or perform a "PCR purification" on your digested DNA samples, this also removes any protein present and therefore prevents star activity.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Why the scare quotes, though?

Comment: Additionally you can run the reaction in PCR tubes in the thermocycler. Simply choose the temperature you want to have it and then ramp up to 10 min at 65°C afterwards. No extra work needed and very convenient.

Comment: @Chris That was exactly what I meant. Sorry for being unclear. Edited answer.

Comment: @Chris WYSIWYG edited the answer to "PCR purification" (you can check the log). I was unsure why this was formatted as such.

Comment: Ah, now. I usually run these reactions in PCR tubes in the thermocycler, because the volume is small anyway and it is very convenient.

Comment: @MarchHo the quotes because it is not really a standard name of the procedure I guess. This term is popularized by Qiagen :P   You can remove it if you want.